# Roots of trigonometric equation $\sin((n+1)\theta) + 2\sin(n\theta) = 0,\;\;\theta\neq k\pi\,\,k\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, roots

I am trying to find a closed formula for the roots of the following trigonometric equation,
$$\sin((n+1)\theta) + 2\sin(n\theta) = 0,\;\;\theta\neq k\pi\,\,k\in\mathbb{Z},$$ 
where $n$ is a positive integer.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Looking at $n=2$ and $n=3$ in Wolfram Alpha does not look promising. You can probably reduce the problem to solving a $n$-th degree polynomial for $t=\tan(\theta/2)$, but a closed formula seems unattainable.